# INSERT Multiply row in MySQL when i have a list from another table

Tags: php, mysql, while-loop, insert

At the moment I'm stuck at the following point. I have a table with some company where we do some work for. in this table is have the following information.

> - id
> - Projectno.
> - name
> - location

With a select I show them al in one big view. For that I'm using this Select.

```
 $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM vdwerf_strooien_opdrachtgevers WHERE    actief='0' ORDER by id") or die (mysql_error());
 while ($get = mysql_fetch_array($query))
 { 
 }
```

In the view of the result I get i want to put in worked hours divided over every single company.

I have in my form the link as soon i press submit go to `?action=new`.

In there is have the next INSERT which is putting al the company's in, but for the hours it only takes the last record. so for every company the code puts in 2 hours. Even it might that i didn't work for one company the other maybe 1 and another again 2.

```
mysql_query ("INSERT INTO vdwerf_strooien_uren (id, opdrachtgever, dagdeel1) SELECT '', id, '".$_POST[dagdeel1]."' FROM vdwerf_strooien_opdrachtgevers");
```

So now I would like to get some help with the question. If i have 6 or 60 company's how can I insert different hours by every single company when I select all the company's from another table.

the company's are in a table because it can happen that one get cancelled or they add a new company.

Thanks for all the help you will give.

Comment: Hello. Your code is totaly unsafe!!!! You should stop using `mysql_` functions since their deprecated and not longer supported. Also you should NEVER(!!!!!) directly insert `$_POST` values to a query. This way, your database can be deleted by any users in seconds. Take a look at what bobby happened. http://bobby-tables.com/

Comment: @Twinfriends is right you can convert your code to mysqli_ functions and you can use mysqli_real_escape_string. For more info just visit - http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php and http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_real_escape_string.asp

Comment: @AdhanTimothyYounes the `mysqli_real_escape_string` is not safe enough. Simply use prepared statements. http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp